# "Two substances with plasticizer contents of B and Z, and C and Z respectively"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number

I have a problem with the word "content". I wish to describe two mixtures of substances:

- M1:A with plasticizer B, and
- M2:A with plasticizer C.

Both mixtures contain a common third component, plasticizer Z.

Can I say "two substances with plasticizer contents of B and Z, and C and Z respectively" to underline that the plasticizers are different?

Comment: Please use a complete sentence in the example you ask about; as is, your question is unclear.  Unclear questions often are voted down or closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your own word, *component*, seems the best: "...with plasticizer components of B and Z".  But this sounds like a technical context (is a plasticizer usually considered part of a mixture?), in which case you're probably better consulting other papers on the subject and following them,.

Comment: +1 for following what is standard in papers written for the specific field

Answer (score 0):

The phrase as revised,

> two substances with plasticizer contents of B and Z, and C and Z respectively

is clear.  An alternative might be phrased like

> Besides z% of plasticizer Z in each, M1 has x% of X and M2 has y% of Y

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes being too concise makes the reader pause to parse.

Just spell it out: "Mixtures M1:A and M2:A both contain plasticizer Z. Each mixture also contains one additional plasticizer - M1:A contains plasticizer B, and M2:A contains plasticizer C."